# Does there exist a rational polynomial $P(x)\in{\mathbb Q}[x]{}$ such that $P(\zeta(s))=\zeta(P(s))$?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, polynomials, riemann-zeta-function, rational-functions

let $P(x)\in{\mathbb Q}[x]{}$ be a rational polynomial with $P(1) >1$ and $\zeta $ be the Riemann zeta function , I want to know if there exist a rational polynomial such that $P(\zeta(s))=\zeta(P(s))$ with $s>1$ ?

Comment: I have been working on a related problem, and my conclusion is that no injective $P$ fulfilling your requirements exists.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN: Polynomials of degree at least $2$ are not injective on $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Indeed, but the OP doesn't forbid degree $1$ polynomials.

Comment: The question doesn't match with the title.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Extending the argument by GH from MO, $\zeta(P(s))$ has a pole for any $s$ such that $P(s)=1$, while $P(\zeta(s))$ has unique pole for $s=1$. Therefore if $\zeta(P(s))=P(\zeta(s))$, then $P(s)=1$ has unique solution $s=1$ and $P(x)-1=c(x-1)^n$ for some complex $c$ and positive integer $n$, and we get $\zeta(1+c(s-1)^n)=1+c(\zeta(s)-1)^n$. For $s=1+x$ with small $x$ the equality of leading asymptotic terms gives $1/(cx^n)=c/x^n$, $c=\pm 1$. For $s=2$ we get $\zeta(1+c)=1+c(\zeta(2)-1)^n$, i.e., either

(i) $c=1$, $\zeta(2)-1=(\zeta(2)-1)^n$, $n=1$, $P(x)=x$, or

(ii)$c=-1$, $-3/2=-(\zeta(2)-1)^n$, this is impossible (since $0<\zeta(2)-1<1$).

Answer (score 9):

No. If $P$ has a positive leading coefficient, then letting $s$ go to infinity and using continuity of $P$ we get $P(1)=1$. If $P$ has a negative leading coefficient, then $\zeta(P(s))$ has zeros at arbitrarily large $s$, while $P(\zeta(s))$ does not.

Comment: Doesn't your argument also apply for polynomials in $\mathbb{R}[x]$?

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN: There is a simple proof for all complex polynomials. See my post below.

Answer (score 9):

It is straightforward to see that if $P\in\mathbb{C}[x]$ satisfies $P(\zeta(s))=\zeta(P(s))$, then $P(1)=1$. Note that if $P(\zeta(s))=\zeta(P(s))$ holds for all real $s>1$, then it also holds for all complex $s\neq 1$ by the uniqueness of analytic continuation.

Indeed, $\zeta(s)$ has a pole at $s=1$, hence $P(\zeta(s))=\zeta(P(s))$ also has a pole at $s=1$. This implies that $P(1)=1$.

**Added.** It seems easy to show that $P(x)=x$ is the only non-constant polynomial satisfying the conditions. (Indeed, this is true, see Fedor Petrov's response.)

Comment: Can your argument be used to show that any complex function commuting to $\zeta$ is necessarily continuous?

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN, nice idea probably you meant  uses of Voronin's universality to show any commuting complex function to R zeta function must be continious

Comment: @GH from MO  , would be the same simple proof with s lie in the critical strip ?

Comment: @zeraoulia rafik: with $s$ in the critical strip, you get that if $z$ is a non trivial zero of $\zeta$, then $P(\zeta(z))=\zeta(P(z))=P(0)$. As this equality doesn't depend on the zero, it means $P$ is a permutation of the multiset of the non trivial zeros of $\zeta$ and thus $P(0)=0$.

Comment: @zeraouliarafik: If $P(\zeta(s))=\zeta(P(s))$ holds at infinitely many distinct points $(s_1,s_2,\dots)$ with a limit point in $\mathbb{C}$, then it also holds for all complex $s\neq 1$ by the uniqueness of analytic continuation. Hence we infer $P(1)=1$ as before.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN: My intuition is that there are plenty of non-continuous functions commuting with $\zeta$, but I don't want to think about it.

Comment: And as a permutation is bijective, if $P$ is continuous, it is either the identity or the complex conjugation.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN: There are also plenty of continuous functions from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$ that permute the zeros of $\zeta(s)$, not just the identity and complex conjugation.

Comment: But do these functions commute with $\zeta$?

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN: I think there are plenty of continuous and non-continuous functions from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$ that commute with $\zeta$. On the other hand, there probably very few holomorphic of meromorphic functions that commute with $\zeta$. At any rate, I stop here a this site is not a discussion board, and also these questions appear to be pretty random (they have little to do with $\zeta$).

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple argument which applies to polynomials in $C[x]$, and even to most rational functions in $C(x)$. $\zeta$ is a meromorphic function in the plane.
So the Nevanlinna characteristic $T(r,\zeta)$ is defined. It is a positive increasing function, a kind of transcendental analog of the degree of a rational function. Your equation implies
that $(\deg P+o(1))T(r,\zeta)=T(r^d(1+o(1),\zeta).$ Here $d$ is the order of pole
of $P$ at $\infty$, for the case of polynomial, $d=\deg P$, of course.
If $d\leq 0$ then the right hand side is bounded, if $d\geq 1$, we obtain a contradiction since for every transcendental meromorphic function $T(r,f)/\log r\to\infty$. So only the case $d=1$ remains, but for this case the completion of the proof is elementary. Of course I understand that this is too heavy artillery to solve such an elementary question:-)